# Python selenium driver.get error

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I've used selenium to crawl data for around nine months.The code below ran normally last week.

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
chromedriver = 'the path of the driver.exe'
os.enviorn["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
browser.get(url)
```

However, as I tried to run the same code this week, I got the this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line1, in <module>
    browser.get(url)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 213, in get 
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url':url})
  File C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 201, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 188, in check_response 
    raise.exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
WebDriverException: Message:
```

I changed different url and the error message remains the same. In addition, after trying twice the browser.get function, the chrome driver will crash.

Really have no idea what is wrong or what can I do instead?

Comment: Are you sure you pasted the Traceback message **full** ?

Comment: yes... this is all I got

Comment: Did you found any solutions? I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem I used the sleep library with 3 seconds of waiting and it started working again! I don't know for sure I believe I gave the browser time lol

from time import sleep

Answer (score -1):

Please note that the (url) in the browser.get(url) should be a string object.
Kindly try to use the (url) as ('url') and not the name of a string variable.
It has worked for me -- @Hsiang